# Let $f(x)=\frac{d^{100}}{dx^{100}}\frac{1}{100!}x^{100}(1-x)^{100}$ Show that $0<\int^{1}_{0}x^{100}f(x)dx<\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{100}$

Tags: calculus

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem

Q: Let $f(x)=\frac{d^{100}}{dx^{100}}\frac{1}{100!}x^{100}(1-x)^{100}$

Show that

$$0<\int^{1}_{0}x^{100}f(x)dx<\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{100}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do $100$ integration by parts to arrive at

$$\int_0^1x^{100}f(x){\rm d}x = \int_0^1x^{100}(1-x)^{100}{\rm d}x$$

To finish it off show that $0 < x(1-x) \leq \frac{1}{4}$ for $x\in (0,1)$ and use this bound the integral above.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try taking one derivative of $\frac{1}{100!}x^{100}(1-x)^{100}.$

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{100!}x^{100}(1-x)^{100} &=& \frac{1}{100!}(100x^{99}(1-x)^{100}+100(1-x)^{99}x^{100}) \\
&=& \frac{1}{99!}(x^{99}(1-x)^{100}-(1-x)^{99}x^{100}) \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Clearly some of the terms will cancel.  Once you repeat this for one or two more derivatives, can you come up with an explicit rule for taking the $n$th derivative?

After doing that, simplify as much as possible by plugging $f(x)$ into the integral.  Something tells me that you will be able to cancel many terms out and it will be nearly trivial to show that the integral will always be bounded between 0 and $\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{100}.$